# Flutter change focus color and icon color but not works

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

Change focus color and icon color but not work

```
TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.red[600],
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                filled: false,
                iconColor: Colors.red,
                focusColor: Colors.red,
                icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                hintText: 'Where can we reach you?',
                labelText: 'Phone Number *',
                prefixText: '+86',
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              onSaved: (String? value) {
                this._phoneNumber = value;
                print('phoneNumber=$_phoneNumber');
              },
              // TextInputFormatters are applied in sequence.
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ],
            ),
```

I have changed the focus color and icon color to red. I do hot restart but the output still is blue. My theme primary color is also red.

```
theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
```

What is the problem?
Here are the current output.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to change the color of Icon on focus then you can use this instead

```
Color iconColor = Colors.grey;//add this as a variable

//use the focus widget in place of your textfield.
 Focus(
     onFocusChange: (hasFocus)
        {
         if(hasFocus)
             {
               iconColor = Colors.red;
              }
         else{
                iconColor = Colors.grey;
             }
             setState((){});
           },
          child: TextField(
             decoration: InputDecoration(prefix: Icon(Icons.phone, color: iconColor,)),
            ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [offical documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) this is available:

> This sample shows how to style a TextField with a prefixIcon that
> changes color based on the MaterialState through the use of ThemeData.

Your code could therefore be:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    inputDecorationTheme: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
      iconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
          return Colors.red;
        }
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
          return Colors.deepOrange;
        }
        return Colors.grey;
      }),
    ),
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    cursorColor: Colors.red[600],
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
      filled: false,
      icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
      hintText: 'Where can we reach you?',
      labelText: 'Phone Number *',
      prefixText: '+86',
    ),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    onSaved: (String? value) {
      this._phoneNumber = value;
      print('phoneNumber=$_phoneNumber');
    },
    // TextInputFormatters are applied in sequence.
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],
  ),
),
```

The good thing with this is that you can, if you want, set this inputDecorationTheme to be applied for the entire app just once using the `theme` property on the `MaterialApp` widget, and will be applied everywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FocusNode`.

```dart
  late FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

```dart
TextFormField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
  cursorColor: Colors.red[600],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.phone,
      color: focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
    ),
  ),
```

Also, dispose the focus node

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

More about [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)