# Change fill color of InputDecorationTheme on error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change fill color of InputFormField when error occures. But in theme I didn't find property like errorFillColor. So how can I change of InputFormField when state of field changes? Here is my code from theme:

```
 inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppDimension.paddingLarge),
      filled: true,
      iconColor: Colors.black,
      fillColor: AppColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.7),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimension.radiusLarge),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimension.radiusLarge),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimension.radiusLarge),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimension.radiusLarge),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimension.radiusLarge),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
    ),
```

And here is what I need:

[image: Sample image]

Moreover I can't find onErrorIconColor to change color of icon of field.

Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as an example for `fillColor`. Meaning you should follow the same principal for `iconColor`.

```
fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
          return Colors.green;
        }
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
          return Colors.red;
        }
        return Colors.black;
      }),
```

I answered a very similar question a couple of days ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871777/13263384

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to try it. I thought that it'll be possible only with  MaterialStateProperty<Color?>, hah. Where these states are coming from?

Comment: It comes from the widget itself, which tracks its state.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct later after tests. Thank you!